# PHP filename click able to download

Tags: php, html

Hi I need some help adding the file name under each photo and make the name clickable to download the photo if possible. The file name should be the name the photo has been saved with  example if the photo is 123.jpg I want the name to show as 123 and when I click on it it should save it...

```
 <?php
        # SETTINGS
        $max_width = 800;
        $max_height = 600;
        $per_page = 10;

        $page = $_GET['page'];

        $has_previous = false;
        $has_next = false;

        function getPictures() {
            global $page, $per_page, $has_previous, $has_next;
            if ( $handle = opendir(".") ) {
                $lightbox = rand();
                echo '<ul id="pictures">';

                $count = 0;
                $skip = $page * $per_page;

                if ( $skip != 0 )
                    $has_previous = true;

                while ( $count < $skip && ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
                    if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' )
                        $count++;
                }
                $count = 0;
                while ( $count < $per_page && ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
    if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' ) {

        // make the thumbs directory if it doesn't already exist
        if ( ! is_dir('thumbs') ) {
            mkdir('thumbs');
        }
        // make a thumbnail if it doesn't already exist
        if ( ! file_exists('thumbs/'.$file) ) {
            makeThumb( $file, $type );
        }

        // create a link to $file, add the thumbnail
        echo '<li><a href="' . $file . '">';
        echo '<img src="thumbs/'.$file.'" alt="" /></a></li>';
        $count++;
echo '<a href="$file">';
echo substr($file,strlen($folder),strpos($file, '.')-strlen($folder));
echo '</a>';
    }
}
                echo '</ul>';

                while ( ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
                    if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' ) {
                        $has_next = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function getPictureType($file) {
            $split = explode('.', $file); 
            $ext = $split[count($split) - 1];
            if ( preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/i', $ext) ) {
                return 'jpg';
            } else if ( preg_match('/png/i', $ext) ) {
                return 'png';
            } else if ( preg_match('/gif/i', $ext) ) {
                return 'gif';
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }

        function makeThumb( $file, $type ) {
            global $max_width, $max_height;
            if ( $type == 'jpg' ) {
                $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            } else if ( $type == 'png' ) {
                $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            } else if ( $type == 'gif' ) {
                $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            }
            if ( ($oldW = imagesx($src)) < ($oldH = imagesy($src)) ) {
                $newW = $oldW * ($max_width / $oldH);
                $newH = $max_height;
            } else {
                $newW = $max_width;
                $newH = $oldH * ($max_height / $oldW);
            }
            $new = imagecreatetruecolor($newW, $newH);
            imagecopyresampled($new, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newW, $newH, $oldW, $oldH);
            if ( $type == 'jpg' ) {
                imagejpeg($new, 'thumbs/'.$file);
            } else if ( $type == 'png' ) {
                imagepng($new, 'thumbs/'.$file);
            } else if ( $type == 'gif' ) {
                imagegif($new, 'thumbs/'.$file);
            }
            imagedestroy($new);
            imagedestroy($src);
        }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UFT-8" />
    <title>Pictures</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        width:780px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #pictures li {
        float:left;
        height:<?php echo ($max_height + 10); ?>px;
        list-style:none outside;
        width:<?php echo ($max_width + 10); ?>px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    img {
        border:0;
        outline:none;
    }
    .prev {
        float:left;
    }
    .next {
        float:right;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php getPictures(); ?>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <?php
        if ( $has_previous )
            echo '<p class="prev"><a href="?page='.($page - 1).'">&larr; Previous Page</a></p>';

        if ( $has_next )
            echo '<p class="next"><a href="?page='.($page + 1).'">Next Page &rarr;</a></p>';
    ?>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, the code you're using generates thumbnails for each image, but it does not create a link to the image, which is what you need to be able to click and load the pictures. There is also some extra code that looks like it is from a different script that adding unneeded html to your page.

To add a link to the images, you'll need to replace the appropriate part of your code with the following:

```
while ( $count < $per_page && ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
    if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' ) {

        // make the thumbs directory if it doesn't already exist
        if ( ! is_dir('thumbs') ) {
            mkdir('thumbs');
        }
        // make a thumbnail if it doesn't already exist
        if ( ! file_exists('thumbs/'.$file) ) {
            makeThumb( $file, $type );
        }

        // create a link to $file, add the thumbnail
        echo '<li><a href="' . $file . '">';
        echo '<img src="thumbs/'.$file.'" alt="" /></a></li>';
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this make the picture click able and downloadable but I want to show the name of each picture underneath it. I added the following underneath the above section `echo substr($file,strlen($folder),strpos($file, '.')-strlen($folder));
` now it shows the filename but how do I change it into a hyperlink to download once I click on it...

Comment: You just need to add `<a href="$file">` and `</a>` around the text that you want linked.

Comment: ok it open up the jpg file in another page, but isn't there a way to directly save it... anyways how should i go if I wish to sort it from newest to oldest by date?

Comment: Create a new question for the sorting problem since it's a different issue.